# Unable to run npm start after deploying NextJS app on Azure App Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, next.js

I am trying to deploy Next.js app from a mono repo to azure appservice (linux) but with partial success. While I can see the package deployed in Data/SitePackages but startup command (npm start) fail to  start the application. Config settings for the appservice has WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1. It appears that server has no reference to node_modules. Do i need to do npm install in the dist/apps/xxx folder for node_modules then deploy to azure?. Appreciate your inputs for solving the issue

**Error:**

```
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979869309Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" next start
2022-12-08T05:49:36.987850176Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 11: /opt/startup/startup.sh: next: 
not found
```

**Release pipeline script**

```
- task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Build'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          workingDirectory: $(WorkingDir)
          script: |
            config="development"
            npx nx affected --target=build --configuration $config --parallel --maxParallel=10 
            --base=$(Base)
        continueOnError: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/apps/xxx'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/apps/xxx.zip'
          includeRootFolder: false
        enabled: true
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
       displayName: 'Deploy'
       inputs:
          ConnectionType: AzureRM
          azureSubscription: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-contributor'
          appType: webApp
          ResourceGroupName: 'xx-eus2-dev-xxx-appqxxx-rg'
          WebAppName: 'xxx-xxx-webapp'
          package:  '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/apps/xxx.zip'
          DeployToSlotOrASEFlag: true
          SlotName: DEV
          StartupCommand: 'npm start'
      continueOnError: false
```

**Azure Log Stream**

```
/home/LogFiles/2022_12_08_ln0sdlwk00000B_default_docker.log  (https://xxx-xxx- 
webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_12_08_ln0sdlwk00000B_default_docker.log)
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979836609Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979841809Z 
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979846709Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979851109Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979855809Z      export PORT=8080
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979860309Z fi
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979865109Z 
2022-12-08T05:49:36.979869309Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" next start
2022-12-08T05:49:36.987850176Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: 11: /opt/startup/startup.sh: next: not 
found


2022-12-08T05:49:40.728Z INFO  - Container xxx-xxx-webapp_1_7deaa4c2_middleware for site xx- 
xxx-webapp initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2022-12-08T05:49:40.739Z ERROR - Container xxx-xxx-webapp_1_7deaa4c2 didn't respond to HTTP 
pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-12-08T05:49:40.744Z INFO  - Stopping site xxx-xxx-webapp because it failed during 
startup.
```

**Package.json** of the app after the build

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "next start"
 }
```

**Azure AppService Configuration**
[image]

Comment: Hi, Did you find the solution for this problem, I am also facing the similar issue.
I am also running Azure NextJS app from Package and Startup command is giving me below error.
Startup Command - npm run start:production
and Package.Json has script
"start:production": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start"
And i am getting the Error-
sh: 1: node_modules/next/dist/bin/next: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

- Here using this yaml file and I was able to deploy the nextjs app to azure app service.

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App 

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
    workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - name: Set up Node.js version
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                node-version: '16.x'
            - name: npm install, build, and test
              run: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
                npm run test --if-present

            - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
              with:
                name: node-app
                path: .
                
        deploy:
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
            needs: build
            environment:    
                name: 'Production'
                url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
            steps:
                - name: Download artifact from build job
                  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
                  with:
                    name: node-app
                    
                - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
                  id: deploy-to-webapp
                  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
                  with:
                    app-name: 'v-mganorkarnext'
                    slot-name: 'Production'
                    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<pulblish profile>}}

                    package: .
```

[image]

This way there won't be a need to add startup commands and even if you want to run them first run `npm install`  then `npm run build` and then `next start`